# Where is "The Unit Test Metadata file"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

According to the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx:

"When you run MSTest.exe, you must specify either a test metadata file or a test container, using either the /testmetadata option or the /testcontainer option, respectively. You use the /testmetadata option only once, to indicate one test metadata file. You can use the /testcontainer option multiple times, to indicate multiple test containers."

Ok, great. Where is this mysterious Metadata file? Is it something I need to create? Did the project template create it for me?

I also found, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182461(v=vs.90).aspx says, "Test lists reside in test metadata files, which in turn reside in the Solution Items folder of a solution. As you add, delete, or change test lists, or add tests to test lists or remove tests from them, their descriptions are updated in the metadata file. The metadata file is an XML file."

Interesting. I have no "Solution Items folder."

I made my unit test project via the unit test project template at File->New->Project - Visual C#-> Test

It created no such folder or file.

Where do I find this file or how do I create it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#testmetadata

Comment: Most likely, you just want to run `mstest /testcontainer:"TheDllContainingTheUnitTests.dll"` to run *all* the unit tests.

Comment: "The test metadata file is created for your solution when you create test lists using the Test List Editor window". Lol @ Microsoft, OK where is the "Test Lists Editor Window? I see no such thing anywhere. I've got a test explorer, but it doesnt cause any files to be created, not even with playlists. mstest /testcontainer:"TheDllContainingTheUnitTests.dll" works if I only have 1 dll, but I do indeed have multiple unit test projects to run. I suppose I could just run them one dll at a time with a bat file, but I feel like I am missing a feature here.

Comment: You can only create vsmdi files up to VS2010. In the later SKU's the feature was left out, IIRC.

Comment: Unless you really need to support mstest.exe you might be better served with [vstest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I'll just work around it. thanks!